# как реализовать блок с выбором свойств товара

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

-

вот есть блок(сколько всего таких блоков тоже пока неизвестно),
несколько нужных пунктов я знаю заранее, их пользователь видит сразу;

а другая их часть скрыта и сколько их будет можно узнать только из базы данных.
как мне сверстать этот блок так, чтобы при добавлении хоть 40 пунктов из бд(*показать еще*) ничего не разъехалось и пункты выглядели одинаково?

-

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*после нажатия на "показать еще"* /\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсмотрите как это сделано на других сайтах.

Пример с яндекс макркета

до:

[image: до]

после

[image: после]

```js
//условный фетч до сервера
const getData = new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(()=>
  resolve({
    data: new Array(15).fill(6).map((e,i)=>e+i)
  }), 1000
))

//создание элемента
const createFilterItem = (itemData) => {
  const item = document.createElement('li')
  item.classList.add('filter__item')
  item.textContent = itemData
  return item
}

//обработчик "показать ещё"
const handleClickShowMore = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  try {
    const resp = await getData
    resp.data.reduce((acc, elem)=>
    acc.appendChild(createFilterItem(elem)), document.querySelector('.filter__list'))
    event.target.textContent = "скрыть" 
    event.target.onclick = handleClickHide
  } catch (err) {
    //обработать ошибку, если данные не получены
  }
}

//обработчик "скрыть"
const handleClickHide = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('filter__item')) //ищем элементы списка
    .slice(5, -1) //отбрасываем первых 5
    .forEach((item)=>item.remove())//удаляем
  event.target.textContent = "показать ещё" 
  event.target.onclick = handleClickShowMore
}

//назначаем обработчик
document.querySelector('.filter__toggler').onclick = handleClickShowMore
```

```css
.filter__list {
  max-height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <ul class="filter__list">
    <li class="filter__item">1</li>
    <li class="filter__item">2</li>
    <li class="filter__item">3</li>
    <li class="filter__item">4</li>
    <li class="filter__item">5</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="filter__toggler" href="#">показать еще</a>
</div>
```

Comment: В обычной жизни, чтобы включать/выключать отображение всего списка, либо только пяти первых пунктов достаточно переключения класса active у родительского блока, а также селектора типа `li:nth-child(-n+5)`

Comment: Это лишь пример с переназначающими друг друга функциями, в нем при каждом нажатии на "показать" происходит запрос списка фильтров, не хотелось лишними проверками усложнять.